# Site collection Validation

Tags: backup, site, restore, validation

While restoring a site collection, what all properties can be taken into consideration for validating the restore.
(Say for example, if I have a a properties of the site before backing it up.. And I compare these properties with the restored site properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Restoring you can activate PowerShell switch `-verbose`. This will provide on screen information about what is actually happening during the Restore Process.

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionURL> -Path <Backup file> [-DatabaseServer <DatabaseServerName>] [-DatabaseName <ContentDatabaseName>] [-HostHeader <Host header>] [-Force] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

Once you verify there is not error. The Restore will be 100% valid from data point of view.

The area you should actually look into should be Customized things like web part , styles etc.